# Adding content dynamically on click of next not working properly

Tags: dynamic, caroufredsel

I have slider having 5 images in each. I am loading 10 images already on page load.
on click of "next" I am adding another 5 images using insertitem.
but when I click on "Next" it is going to 3rd page instead of 2nd and content is loaded on second page instead of third.

so in pagination bullets, 3rd bullet is selected but images are inserted at second page. ideally it should be reversed so, on selected bullet should be second page and inserted item should be loaded on 3rd page.

Here is the code I have used:

```
$("#carousel").carouFredSel({
circular : false,
infinite : false,
auto : false,
responsive : true,
swipe : {
onTouch : true,
onMouse : true,
duration : 300
},
items: {
visible : { min: 2, max: 5},
width : 210,
height : "76%"
},
scroll:5,
prev : {
button : "#prev",
duration : 500
},
next : {
button : "#next",
duration : 500,
onAfter: function( data ) {
// this is a fake AJAX request, you should use the real deal.
fakeAjax({
url: 'your/url',
success: function( newitems ) {
$('#carousel').trigger( 'insertItem', [$(newitems), "end" , false, 0] );
},
error: function(err){
alert(err);
}
});
}
},
pagination : {
container : "#pag",
duration : 500
}
});
// The fake AJAX function:
var num = 1, max = 10;
function fakeAjax( options ) {
num++;
if (num );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "false", putting "true" for the origOrder Parameter solved the Issue for me

```
$('#carousel').trigger('insertItem', [data.popup_images, 'end', true, -1]);
```